# Turn Aside and Noxious Gearhulk

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When [Noxious Gearhulk](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNoxious%20Gearhulk%5d) is played can it be countered by [Turn Aside](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTurn%20Aside%5d)?

I've noticed that some cards say "counter target spell or creature" but turn aside only says "counter target spell ..."

Comment: "Counter target spell or creature" is not a valid wording for any Magic card. If you are thinking of a specific example of the wording you're thinking about, please name the card.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No, Turn aside cannot counter Noxious Gearhulk.**

There seems to be some confusion here. When a player plays a creature spell such as the Gearhulk, it is indeed a spell while it is on the stack and does fulfill one of the conditions of Turn Aside's possible targets. However, a creature spell (generally, all permanent spells except Auras) never targets anything, and is therefore never a valid target for Turn Aside. A creature spell is simply on the stack, and when it resolves, it puts the creature it represents onto the battlefield.

Only the Gearhulk's enters-the-battlefield ability can target something. It goes on the stack when the Gearhulk has resolved and entered the battlefield. However, an ability is not the same as a spell, Turn Aside can counter only spells, so Turn Aside cannot counter that ability either.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot counter a Gearhulk with Turn Aside.

The Gearhulk is not a spell that targets anything. When it's cast, it's just a creature spell on the stack, without any targets and doing nothing special. Its ability isn't doing anything yet.

*After* Gearhulk resolves and enters the battlefield as a creature (too late to counter it), its *"When Noxious Gearhulk enters the battlefield..."* ability triggers and goes on the stack. Now there is a *triggered ability* on the stack that's targeting something. You'd have to cast a card like [Stifle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStifle%5d) which counters *that* ability.